# Is dockeroperator got any changes in airflow 2.5.3 version?

Tags: docker, airflow

When I am trying to execute the python command with airflow user in terminal with docker its working fine, but when I am using through airflow as a docker operator its not recognizing the files, getting file not found error .

This is being seen in airflow 2.5.3 version, in 2.1.0 its working fine; trying to understand if any changes in this version on dockeroperator.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that [apache-airflow](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/) and providers (like: [apache-airflow-providers-docker](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-docker/) ) and not coupled. Providers are released independently.

Thus, when you update your Airflow version you need also to check if depended packages had breaking changes since breaking change of depended package doesn't mean breaking change for Airflow.

I'm assuming that you are installing Airflow according to the recommended way of using the [official constrains](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/installation/installing-from-pypi.html#installation-from-pypi) thus you need to check which version of docker provider was defined in the 2.1.0 constraints and what version is being defined in 2.5.3 then check the docker provider change log to see what were the breaking changes.

Since you didn't mention which Python version you are using I'll assume that it's 3.9 (if you use different version then adjust the links accordingly)

Airflow 2.1.0 Python 3.9 constraints:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.1.0/constraints-3.9.txt

This constraint file points to:

```
apache-airflow-providers-docker==1.0.1
```

Airflow 2.5.3 Python 3.9 constraints:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.5.3/constraints-3.9.txt

This constraint file points to:

```
apache-airflow-providers-docker==3.5.1
```

This means you need to check `the apache-airflow-providers-docker` [change log](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-docker/stable/index.html) from version 1.0.1 to 3.5.1 and see what were the breaking changes.
Since packages follows [SemVer](https://semver.org/) it's easy to understand which version had major changes. You can just follow the change log as listed above and check which change applys to you.